# Angular 2 HTTP get handling 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular, http-status-code-404

I have a service which served an empty json, but i am getting these errors. If i use https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/6 then its ok. How can i handle these errors in the correct way?

Service:

```
constructor( private http:Http ) { }

fetchData(){
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/psts/6')
      .map(
          (res) => res.json()
      )
      .subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data)
  );
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: And why are you omitting the `o`?

Comment: @HarryNinh what do you mean?

Comment: Your given URL is `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/6`, and your URL in the code is `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/psts/6`

Comment: This I have done to create an error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass a second callback to the subscribe method. This callback will execute when there is an error.

```
function handleError(error) {
  console.log(error)
}

fetchData(){
  return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/psts/6')
      .map(
          (res) => res.json()
      )
      .subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data),
        (error) => handleError(error)
  );
}
```

Comment: i am getting ReferenceError: handleError is not defined

Comment: You need to define the handle error function. you can console log or do what ever you want with the error.

Comment: I just added the handleError function to the answer

Comment: Ok, almost there, i get a response, its this.handleError(error) and the function whitout function. How can i get ride of GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/psts/6 404 () in the console?

Comment: This is not in your control. That's how browsers works, you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem in your code, the [URL](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/psts/6) itself is giving a **404**

Comment: But i am getting al kind of red errors in my console, thats not good ;)

Comment: @Bas It's the URL, which is giving you the **404**, this means that the resource you're looking for is not found. A code cannot fix this, the URL's server guy needs to have some resource at this URL